How to fix my dropdown display overlapping with each other?
After a lot of struggle, I finally managed to get my dropdown buttons to display at the top of the screen, fit in the navbar, and appear next to each other. However, now the dropdown menus for both are overlayed on each other and both drop under the "About Us" section instead of their respective button.
Here is a screenshot of my site.


#headbar {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 2px black solid;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

#logo {
  display: inline;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
}

#title {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    min-width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.button-container {
    display: flex;
    left: 190px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#button-1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#button-2 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}

  .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
  }
.dropdown-content a {
color: white;
padding: 8px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}
  
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ff0000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #ff0000;
}
<nav id="navbar">
<header id="headbar">
   <h1 id="title">DAILY</h1><img id="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/C7wkQsw/DB-Logo.png" alt="Daily Bugle Logo"><h1 id="title">BUGLE</h1>
<div class="button-container">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"  id="button-1">About Us</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_1">What We Are</a>
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_2">Journalist Oath</a>
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_3">Editors</a>
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_4">Writers</a>
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_5">Photographers</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" id="button-2">Politics</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_1">Super-Politics</a>
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_2">Local</a>
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_3">United States</a>
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_4">Global</a>
         <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_5">Galactic</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
</nav>



I'm not sure what to put for what I've tried because I've been messing with this for 2 hours and have a poor memory.

Sorry if I did this wrong. I'm new to the CS field.

I would recommend you to read more about html and css while practicing. But lets talk about issue's.
As a beginner avoid using position: absolute unless you know what you are doing. You can achieve any structure using display: flex so try to use that.
You have added many unnecessary css which I have removed and added required css to make logo and header align center which is display: flex, align-items: center and margin: 0 to h1. Below is working example. If you have any doubt please share in comments.
Edited
The dropdown alignments is messed because using position: abolute without adding position: relative to parent div. Add position: relative to .dropdown class and it will work normally. I have also updated below code.


body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .mainDiv {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #1e1e1e;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        #headbar {
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 50px;
            z-index: 2;
            border: 2px black solid;
            background-color: #ff0000;
            /* Newly added */
            display: flex;
        }

        #logo {
            display: inline;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            border: none;
        }


        #button-1 {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: inline;
            border: none;
            border: 2px solid black;
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #button-2 {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: inline;
            border: none;
            border: 2px solid black;
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #f68484;
            min-width: auto;
            box-shadow: 10px 8px 16px 0px black;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        /* Newly added */

        .logo-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .logo-container h1 {
            margin: 0
        }

        dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }
<div class="mainDiv">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <header id="headbar">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <h1 id="title">DAILY</h1><img id="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/C7wkQsw/DB-Logo.png" alt="Daily Bugle Logo">
        <h1 id="title">BUGLE</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" id="button-1">About Us</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_1">What We Are</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_2">Journalist Oath</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_3">Editors</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_4">Writers</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_5">Photographers</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" id="button-2">Politics</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_1">Super-Politics</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_2">Local</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_3">United States</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_4">Global</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_5">Galactic</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </nav>
</div>




All of that worked, but the dropdown content issue is persisting. I did just realize I forgot to include that code though.

I updated the post, but I also realized, there's a black/grey background that fills the view height and centers a lot of things, but now I'm not sure how to put the page content on the screen.

@JacksonChassereau I have updated my responses to make dropdown work, check that out.

I have tried to fix all problems in your HTML and CSS. I also have tried to keep the design same.
Here is the updated code:


header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-title {
  display: flex;
}

#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.drop-btn {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f68484;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 10px 8px 16px 0px black;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content .nav-link {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav id="navbar">
        <div class="logo-title">
          <h1 class="title">DAILY</h1>
          <img
            id="logo"
            src="https://i.ibb.co/C7wkQsw/DB-Logo.png"
            alt="Daily Bugle Logo"
          />
          <h1 class="title">BUGLE</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="drop-btn" type="button">
              About Us
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_1">What We Are</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_2">Journalist Oath</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_3">Editors</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_4">Writers</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_5">Photographers</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="drop-btn" type="button">
              Politics
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_1">Super-Politics</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_2">Local</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_3">United States</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_4">Global</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="#Section_5">Galactic</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>



